# How to write to UART1 in Freescale p1022 using U-Boot?

Tags: uart, u-boot

I know that UART0 is used as U-Boot's console input and output. I would like to be able to write data to the UART1, which is connected with another device, but I cannot find how to configure U-Boot to use it.

Comment: *"I cannot find how to configure U-Boot to use it"* -- "Configure" as in determining what "CONFIG_*" option to enable, or where to put the initialization code, or how to perform the hardware initialization??? UART1 would not be necessary to perform any booting task, so it's not likely that there would already be code to initialize such superfluous hardware.  Nor would there be a configuration option to enable it.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be code to initialize UART1 somewhere. My task is to implement hardware tests in U-Boot, and not just boot the system. Seems like I will have to implement the driver that would do that. But thank you for the comment, @sawdust .

Comment: If you need to perform these tests on every boot, then add the HW initialization to the board file, where Ethernet and USB are initialized.  If the tests are of the diagnostic or offline type, then consider loadable subprograms.  Check out the **examples/standalone** directory which has a *hello_world* demo program.

Comment: Also study the U-Boot documentation for scripting capability.  Also the option to add a shell.